# How to switch strokes of the grease pencil in 2D Animation mode?

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, 2d

I searched but could not find a duplicate.

I want to apply a modifier to only some parts of my animation. My idea was to create separate stroke objects (Add -> Grease Pencil -> Stroke). However, I cannot seem to easily switch between which stroke I'm drawing with. I did manage to do it by accident, and now if I select the different stroke in object mode, I can draw with it later. But that's a lot of work to switch strokes.

Selecting the different stroke in the outliner does change the timeline data so it corresponds with the new stroke, but does not switch the materials, and does not let me draw with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Draw mode or Edit mode you can click since Version 2.91 ([See patch note](https://developer.blender.org/rB2110af20f5e6)) in the outliner on the left column of the row of your object to switch to editing this object.

See :

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is great! I was on version 2.9 but immediately upgraded to 2.91. In addition to this answer, I encourage others to check out Josh Senfelici's comment on my answer below for some useful info about applying modifiers to specific layers.

Comment: Yup, there is actually plenty of options scattered around, and it's improving with each Version :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found cumbersome way to do this a bit after posting this question. If someone knows a quicker way, please post it as an answer and I will accept it.

First, switch from draw mode to object mode. Then, select the new stroke in the outliner (you should see the materials change appropriately). Finally, switch back into draw mode and you should be able to draw with the new stroke.

Comment: Into a single Grease Pencil object, in edit mode you can select some strokes, press M and move them into a new layer, then in the modifiers panel you can limit the action of the modifier to a single layer (or a single material, or a single vertex group). Maybe it's helpful.